# vue navigation submenu component

Tags: vue.js

i am just learning vue 3. If the menu has a child, I want to start a different component, but I couldn't quite figure out how to do it.
I wanted to write as an example what I want to do. Thank you from now.

I'm having trouble describing myself, I hope you don't mind my explanation.

```
<div class="navigation-group">
<div class="navigation-basic-item">Home</div>
<div class="navigation-basic-item">about</div>
<div class="navigation-collapsable-item">subtitle</div>
</div>
```

LayoutDense.vue

```
<template>
    <NavigationGroup :menu="menuItem"/>
</template>

<script>
import NavigationGroup from "./Navigation/NavigationGroup";

export default {
    name: "LayoutDense",
    components: {NavigationGroup},
    data() {
        return {
            menuItem: [
                {
                    name: 'home',
                    path: '/home',
                    Icon: 'home',
                },
                {
                    name: 'about',
                    path: '/about',
                    Icon: 'about'
                },
                {
                    name: 'subtitle',
                    path: '/subtitle',
                    Icon: 'subtitle',
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'sub 1',
                            path: 'sub1',
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'sub 2',
                            path: 'sub2',
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

NavigationGroup.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="navigation-group">
        <slot>
            <template v-for="(link,Index) in menu">
                <navigation-item v-if="link.children===0" :link="link"/>
                <template v-else v-for="(subLink, SubIndex) in link.children">
                    <navigation-collapsable :sub="subLink"/>
                </template>
            </template>
        </slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavigationItem from "./NavigationItem";
import NavigationCollapsable from "./NavigationCollapsable";

export default {
    name: "NavigationGroup",
    components: {
        NavigationItem,
        NavigationCollapsable
    },
    props: {
        menu: {
            type: Object,
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we get your actual result or maybe some more information? You want to use another component for the children items? Or do you want just an iterable component to create your list passing your children as an argument?

Comment: What I want to do is
When I list "menu", if the list has children in it, I want to show it as a different div.

Comment: You can try something like this to flatten your result and render it as it is:
`function getData(tree) {
    if (tree && typeof tree[0].children === "undefined") return tree[0].name;
    var outputString = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
        if (typeof tree[i].children != "undefined") {
          outputString.push(tree[i].name, getData(tree[i].children));
        } else {
          outputString.push(tree[i].name);
        }
    }

    return outputString.toString().split(",");
}`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you edit the answer?